# Colocar icones um do lado do outro gerados automaticamente no javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Gostaria que ficasse um do lado do outro. Toda vez que o cliente faz o upload de contrato ele fica na horizontal. Gostaria de ficasse na vertical.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código:

```
var txt = "";

if (json.code == 1) {
   $(json.data).each(function () {  
       txt += '<div class="center" id="link-Contrato">'
       txt += '<a class="link-pop-up red" href="#" data-url="' + this.urlcontrato + '" data-width="10px"><i style="font-size: 24pt;" class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i></a><br>';
       txt += '    <span><a class="link-pop-up" target="_blank" href="' + this.urlcontrato + '">Contrato</a></span><br><br>'
       txt += '    <span><strong>' + this.tipo_contrato + '</strong></span><br>'

       if (this.detalhamento == "") {
          txt += ''
       } else {
          txt += '    <span><strong>' + this.detalhamento + '</strong></span><br>'
       }
       txt += '    <span><strong>' + this.data_upload + '</strong></span><br>'
       txt += '</div></div><br>'
   });

   } else {
       txt += '<span>Nenhum histórico encontrado.</span>';
   }
   $('#link-Contrato').html(txt);
},
```

Comment: já tentou usar `display: inline-block` por exemplo?

Comment: Usando CSS: div.nomedoicone { float: left; } substituindo o "div.nomedoicone" pela classe que envolve o ícone, container ou lista que você usa para mostrar os arquivos